# Writing Plain Text and DataFrames to CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file-io

I am working with a file format that requires 2-3 header or indicator lines as well as tabular-formatted data. At the moment, I am using the code below to accomplish the task.

sevTmp and sceTmp are two tab-delimited text files where I've temporarily written my data frames. To be clear, these data frames were written to the files using each of their respective to_csv() methods.

Code Examples

```
severitiesELD.to_csv(sevTmp, sep = '\t', \
columns = severitiesELD.columns, index = False, header = severitiesCols)

scenariosELD.to_csv(sceTmp, sep = '\t', \
columns = scenariosELD.columns, index = False, header = scenariosCols)
```

In the block below, I read them into memory and insert a couple other lines (actual text and spacing) per the constructs of the file format. sevString / sceString represent two of the required lines aside from the data frame data

Those lines:

```
sevString = '#Severities\n'
sceString = '#Scenarios\n'
```

I'd love to avoid writing out/reading back in the data frames and write them (for the first time) in one shot along with my indicator strings. My solution below is working quite well, but want to speed things up if possible. Would love suggestions on best to do so while I continue to research alternatives in parallel.

```
with open(sevTmp,'r') as sevF:
    with open(sceTmp, 'r') as sceF:
        with open(finalFile,'w') as finalF:
            # Write the severities line
            finalF.write(sevString)

            # Write out the actual ELD data, and loss cause names
            finalF.write(sevF.read())

            # Add a space
            finalF.write('\n')

            # Add in the scenarios string
            finalF.write(sceString)

            # Add in data frame again, this time to test writing out second time
            finalF.write(sceF.read())
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's not clear to me how `finalF.write(sevF.read())` does anything different to simply writing the DF as you did to the temporary file.

Comment: Please don't include it as a comment, please make sure you edit it in to the original question.

Comment: If your code is working without errors, it may better fit on [codereview.se]. Make sure to check their guidelines.